# How do I automate CPAN configuration?

Tags: perl, cpan

The first time you run cpan from the command line, you are prompted for answers to various questions. How do you automate cpan and install modules non-interactively from the beginning?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since it hasn't been mentioned yet, [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus) is a zero-conf cpan installer. And you can download a self-contained executable if it isn't available for your version control.

The cpanm executable is easily installed (as documented in the executable itself) with:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade
# or
wget -O - http://cpanmin.us | perl - --self-upgrade
```

Answer (score 35):

I was looking for an easy solution for this as well and found that this works:

```
(echo y;echo o conf prerequisites_policy follow;echo o conf commit)|cpan
```

Just thought I would post it here in case anyone else comes along.

Comment: This worked nicely to get cpan configured in Docker.

Comment: mine was just `echo | cpan`, because the first question was `"automate as much as possible [yes]?"`

Answer (score 8):

Make your own CPAN.pm config file. The recent versions of the `cpan` command have a `-J` switch to dump the current config and a `-j` switch to load whatever config you like.

I added these switches because we were distributing CPAN on a CD, back in the days when a MiniCPAN could fit in under 700Mb. You'd run `cpan` as normal but with an added option:

```
% cpan -j /CD/Volume/path/cpan_config.pm ....
```

In that example, the config would set the URL list to the CD path. I've long since lost the source files, but I recall there was a way that it figured out dynamically where it was, or maybe had a program that did and saved the config somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of CPAN.pm ask as first question whether the rest of the configuration should be run automatically, so it is advisable to upgrade CPAN.pm (manually) first: [tarballs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN), [repo](https://github.com/andk/cpanpm).

Answer (score 4):

One way is to take the CPAN/Config.pm (or ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm) created after one run from one system, and install it as ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm on the system you want to automate. Another way is to run the following to create the MyConfig.pm file for you (one thing missing below is the actual values for the urllist parameter which you will have to fill in with appropriate values for CPAN mirrors):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Config;

$ENV{PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT}=1;
$ENV{PERL_MM_NONINTERACTIVE}=1;
$ENV{AUTOMATED_TESTING}=1;

# get the path to the library
my $libpath = $Config{privlib};

# force CPAN::FirstTime to not default to manual
# setup, since initial CPAN setup needs to be automated
{
  local @ARGV = "$libpath/CPAN/FirstTime.pm";
  my @source = <>;
  $source[72] =~ s/\byes\b/no/ or die "Could not auto configure CPAN";
  eval join('', @source) or die "Error executing CPAN::FirstTime: $@";
}

CPAN::FirstTime::init("$libpath/CPAN/Config.pm");

delete $CPAN::Config->{links};
$CPAN::Config->{auto_commit} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{check_sigs} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{halt_on_failure} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{make_install_make_command} = '/usr/bin/make';
$CPAN::Config->{mbuild_arg} = '';
$CPAN::Config->{mbuildpl_arg} = '';
$CPAN::Config->{mbuild_install_arg} = '';
$CPAN::Config->{show_upload_date} = '';
$CPAN::Config->{tar_verbosity} = '1';
$CPAN::Config->{trust_test_report_history} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{use_sqlite} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{yaml_load_code} = '0';
$CPAN::Config->{urllist}
  = [qw(http://... ftp://... etc...)];
$CPAN::Config->{connect_to_internet_ok} = '1';
$CPAN::Config->{perl5lib_verbosity}     = 'v';
$CPAN::Config->{prefer_installer}       = 'MB';
$CPAN::Config->{build_requires_install_policy} = 'no';
$CPAN::Config->{term_ornaments}         = '1';
$CPAN::Config->{mbuild_install_build_command} = './Build';

mkdir ".cpan/CPAN" or die "Can't create .cpan/CPAN: $!";
CPAN::Config->commit(".cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm");

CPAN::install('Bundle::CPAN');
CPAN::install('JSON');
CPAN::install('JSON::XS');
# etc.

exit 0;
```