# Install Perl module with assume yes for given options non-interactively

Tags: perl, cpan

Normally in linux Debian we do sth like this to install a package non-interactively e.g

`sudo apt-get install -y Package_x_z`

```
#[-y --assume-yes]
```

How we can do the same while installing a perl module e.g

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'
```

Comment: Lots of good answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462058/168657).

Comment: any reason for down-voting ? have some courage to write a sentence plz. Which is more useful for everyone

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To prevent the CPAN client from asking whether to install prerequisites, start it in interactive mode

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

and enter the commands:

```
o conf build_requires_install_policy yes
o conf prerequisites_policy follow
o conf commit
```

The `commit` command is optional, but it will update the default configuration, which I suspect is what you want.  Without it, you may or may not (depending on whether `autocommit` is enabled in your CPAN config) need to make this change every time you want to do a prompt-less installation.

These changes will deal with all of the CPAN client's routine questions about whether to install dependencies.  For distributions which have questions embedded in their install scripts, you may also want to add

```
o conf inactivity_timeout 60
```

to set how long it will wait for a response before automatically going with the default answer to the question.  (Set it to 0 to change it back to "wait forever".)

Comment: Is there any way to do this non-interactively?  I have a use case where I need to automate this for several serves, so I'm hoping it's possible to execute this in a single command...

Answer (score 36):

That prompt is (typically) coming from ExtUtils::MakeMaker's prompt() function. Stick `export PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1` in your .bashrc (or equivalent for your preferred shell) to stop the prompts. The ExUtils::MakeMaker man page documents it thus:

> #### PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT
>
> If set to a true value then MakeMaker's prompt function will always return the default
>      without waiting for user input.

Note that this can come to bite you if you run cpan(1) on a box that's not yet had CPAN repositories configured. It will rattle on and get stuck in a prompt loop at a point where there is no default and you need to make a choice, but have no ability to do so. `export PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=0` in the shell before running cpan(1) will of course temporarily re-enable input.

Answer (score 6):

What about just :

```
$ yes | sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'
```

Ban ! your problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Appending to an answer here, you can also make these changes in config file located at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Config.pm.

```
'build_requires_install_policy' => q[yes],
'prerequisites_policy' => q[follow],
```

This helped me to automate installation, since CPAN doesn't have these configuration by default.